# Can block timestamp be smaller than the time a transaction has been sent?

Tags: blocks, timestamp

I have seen cases where the time that I sent my `transaction` (logged on local PC) is actually 'later' (by 10s of seconds) than the `block.timestamp` of the `block` that my `transaction` entered. I checked if computer's `ntp` daemon was working correctly, and everything seems fine.

So, I wonder, is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: How do you log the transaction? Before the transaction has been sent or after it the (async) result returns. Can you provide the code of the transaction?